# CSS div position with float left

Tags: html, css

So i have a css class
`.div{
  width:300px;
  height:auto;
  float:left;}`

If all divs have same height i get this result
[image: normal]

But if second div has greater height than first div i get this result. The problem is third div(the red one). It should directly under first div.
[image: wrong result]

I want my result to look like this but i can't get it there. I can't use tables because to change everything in solution would take to much time that we don't have.
[image: expected result]

Comment: This is not possible using floats.

Comment: Do you know maybe how can i do this?